# regex - split on a character only if there are spaces before and after

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string only if there's a space before and after that character. In my case the character is the dash i.e '-'

Example

```
Opzione - AAAA-11
```

Should be Splitted in

```
Opzione   AAAA-11
```

and not in

```
Opzione AAAA 11
```

Language is python.

Thanks

Comment: `(?<=\s)-(?=\s)` this will be enough

Comment: Thanks, post comment as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookaround

```
(?<=\s)-(?=\s)
```

- `(?<=\s)` -> Positive look behind. condition to check preceding space.
- `-` -> Matches `-`.
- `(?=\s)` -> Positive lookahead matches following space

**On side note** - `\s` will match `\r` , `\t` and `\n` also if you just want to consider space only you can have like this

`(?<= )-(?= )`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regex but how about with non-regex way using `split()` and `join()`

```
str = 'Opzione - AAAA-11';
df = ' '.join(str.split(' - '))
print(df)
```

Comment: I think the dash was only an example, it may be any char enclosed between to spaces

Comment: @Gsk agreed sir, then regex is a good option but OP said **In my case the character is the dash i.e '-'**

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree that regex would be the best option, because in the case that character is a regex meta character, then it can possibly become a whole new headache, even more so if the user isn't knowledgeable about regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
str="Opzione - AAAA-11"
str=re.sub('(\s([\S])\s[\S]?)','',str)
```

This `(\s([\S])\s[\S]?)` means anything , except a space , between two spaces then anything except a whitespace or not and by this you will be able to match like `g h h g`.

So , both `h` are between two spaces but when you match only with `\s([\S])\s` another `h` will not but by `(\s([\S])\s[\S]?)` both will match.